# MVC Architecture - Where to place logic?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm creating a simulation for displaying an automated Maze Solver, in which there is little user input.

The MVC architecture is used and is implemented in Java. The View is to receive and draw data from the Model, through the Controller.

As it stands, I have two options available to update the Model logic and in turn update the View:

- Controller implements Runnable
- Controller creates a thread:

  ```
  Thread runControl = new Thread(this);
  runControl.start();
  ```
- Thread can then execute run() in Controller, which updates the Model logic and pass through the new data to the View

This isn't my preferred method, however, as I'd sooner have the Model running its own logic. I would prefer:

- Model implements Runnable
- Model contains all logic in run()
- Controller creates a Thread for the Model and executes the model

I'm lost at this point. The Model can then update its own logic accordingly, but then whilst the Model Thread is running, how can the Controller be notified of changes in the Model data and in turn retrieve that data (that is still being manipulated/updated) to then notify the View?

Answer (score 1):

Controller and View are tightly tied together.  The former is server side, the latter client side.

I think MVC needs an update that looks like this:

```
View->Controller->Service->Persistence
```

*These* are the layers.  Model runs between layers.

Services fulfill use cases.  They are the proper place to put business logic.  Certainly Model objects should know how to manage their own state, but marshaling Model and Persistence objects to fulfill the use case belongs to the Service.  You need something beyond Model, because Models might not know all the contexts in which they are used.

Controller accepts, validates and binds requests; it determines the Service required to fulfill the request; it serializes the response and determines the next View.

The Service knows the use case and units of work.